# setInterval in NodeJS returns HTTP Error 503

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I'm trying to get requests every hour. Once I `setInterval`, it becomes an Application Error, returning 503 Service Unavailable. Please help!

My code:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
var options = {
    url: 'myURL.com',
    headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': 'key',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

app.use(express.static('public'));

function getData() {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statuscode == 200) {
                res.send(extractinfo(json.parse(body)));
            } else if (!error) {
                res.status(response.statuscode).send([]);
            } else {
                res.send([]);
            }
        });
    });
}
setInterval(getData, 1000*60*60);
```

EDIT: My request will return JSON in body (which it does if I do not setInterval).

```
[  
   {  
      "Course_Schedule_ID":"20",
      "Course_Name":"History of Music",
      "Start_Date":"2016-02-16",
      "Start_Time":"19:30:00"
   },
   {  
      "Course_Schedule_ID":"21",
      "Course_Name":"Science Discovery",
      "Start_Date":"2016-02-21",
      "Start_Time":"14:00:00" 
   }
]
```

Comment: `app.get` does not "get requests". `60000` is not "an hour".

Comment: @tomalak, 6000 is a minute, my bad.

Comment: You should explain your task better. **1)** Who needs to get something, and what do they need to get? **2)** What role does `express` play here? From your description so far you don't even need it at all, so what made you include it in the first place? **3)** Where does the error appear? What do you expect should happen instead?

Comment: @Tomalak, 1) Getting JSON from an external source 2) Express is used to get requests from the url based on given header parameters. 3). The error is shown in the logs (status=503). I expect the JSON to be showed in the body, and it will be refreshed every hour.

Comment: Why is it necessary to rerun `app.get('/', ...)` every hour? You are redefining the listener for the `/` path every hour -- do expect that something destroying that path somehow? Also: if it works without `setInterval`, have you tried... not using `setInterval`? Your question doesn't explain what functionality you hope to add with `setInterval`. My best guess is that you maybe want to cache a resource from this other service for an hour, instead of re-fetching it every time a user hits your service; is that right?

Comment: @apsillers, I'm not sure when there will be an update from the external url, hence I wish to get from the server every hour. There are no user interaction involved, the information will just be displayed. What would be the best way to 'refresh' instead of `setInterval`? Thanks..

Comment: @LilyS I'm really confused about "There are no user interaction involved, the information will just be displayed." Displayed where? In the client's browser? In the server's console? Do you expect a client's browser to suddenly receive a "push" update any time the data is updated, or simply alter the behavior of your service so that the next time the client makes a request, it gets different data?

Comment: @apsillers, yes you are right, I'm altering the service to ensure the next time the client makes a request, it gets the updated data (if any). It will just be displayed on the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set up the service once. You should only make a single `app.get('/', ...)` call when your application starts up, not one call every hour.

Make that `app.get` listener serve the most recent version of the data, and have a separate piece of code update the most recent data.

```
var latestData = {
    data: [],
    status: 200
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(latestData.status).send(latestData.data);
});

// update outer latestData
function getData(callback) {
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statuscode == 200) {
            latestData = {
                data: extractinfo(json.parse(body)),
                status: 200
            };
        } else if (!error) {
            latestData = {
                data: [],
                status: response.statuscode
            };
        } else {
            latestData = {
                data: [],
                status: 200
            };
        }

    });
}
setInterval(getData, 1000*60*60);

// call `getData` immediately so we don't wait an hour for real data
getData();
```